# is this a correct solution for enderton's set theory exercise 3.30?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

### problem 3.30

Assume that $F:{\scr P}A \to {\scr P} A$ and that $F$ has the monotonicity property:
$$
X\subseteq Y \subseteq A \implies F(X)\subseteq F(Y).
$$

Define
$$
B=\bigcap\lbrace X\subseteq A\mid F(X)\subseteq X\rbrace\quad\text{and}\quad C=\bigcup\lbrace X\subseteq A\mid X\subseteq F(X)\rbrace.
$$

(a) Show that $F(B)=B$ and $F(C) = C$. (I'll omit the case of $C$.)

(b) (omitted.)

### solution of yunone.se@gmail.com

the solution in the document *Solutions to Elements of Set Theory* suggested the following solution.

by Theorem 3K, for $X\subseteq A$,
$$
F(B)=F\left(\bigcap_{F(X)\subseteq X} X\right)\subseteq \bigcap_{F(X)\subseteq X} F(X) \subseteq \bigcap_{F(X)\subseteq X} X = B.
$$

Hence $F(B)\subseteq B$, and thus by the monotonicity property, $F(F(B))\subseteq F(B)$, which implies $F(B)\supseteq B$, and thus $F(B)=B$.

(omitted)

#### part of Theorem 3K.

$$
F\left[ \bigcap \scr A \right]\subseteq \bigcap \lbrace F[A]\mid A\in \scr A\rbrace
$$
for nonempty $\scr A$.

($F[X]$ stands for ${\rm ran}(F\upharpoonright A).$)

### my question.

in this solution, it tried to justify its proof by the property of set operator (to a function) by Theorem 3K.

but Theorem 3K said that the property is applied to **the image(range)** of a function, not to the function itself.

so, It seems really odd. if there's no explanation to the relation between the image and the function, I think we can't apply Theorem 3K.

### my last question.

I want to know that:

1. is the former solution either correct or not? if it is correct, can you suggest me some good references to understand it?